Extract the structure detail like name and its member by using the pycparser
I am calling this using a node but function call is not happening. If I call using an AST file class execution is working fine.
class StructVisitor(c_ast.NodeVisitor):
    def visit_Struct(self, node):
        print("Structure Name:", node.name)
        struct_name = node.name
        struct_members = {}
        for member in node.decls:
            member_name = member.name
            member_type = member.type
            struct_members[member_name] = member_type
        structures[struct_name] = struct_members
        print("Structure Members:", structures[struct_name])

class FuncDefVisitor(c_ast.NodeVisitor):
    def visit_FuncDef(self, node):
        print("Function Definition:", node.decl.name)
        struct_visitor = StructVisitor()
        struct_visitor.visit(node)

Is there any solution I can use to call this visit_Struct using node rather than AST file?
class StructVisitor(c_ast.NodeVisitor):
    def visit_Struct(self, node):
        print("Structure Name:", node.name)
        struct_name = node.name
        struct_members = {}
        for member in node.decls:
            member_name = member.name
            member_type = member.type
            struct_members[member_name] = member_type
        structures[struct_name] = struct_members
        print("Structure Members:", structures[struct_name])

class FuncDefVisitor(c_ast.NodeVisitor):
    def visit_FuncDef(self, node):
        print("Function Definition:", node.decl.name)
        struct_visitor = StructVisitor()
        struct_visitor.visit(node)

I am expecting this program to work.

could you put the code formatted in a code block?

You don't have a visit method. You have a visit_Struct method. struct_visitor.visit_Struct(node). Also, why not just: struct_members[member.name] = member.type, and you can get rid of the arbitrary aliasing of these vars.

Ore even better, do this structures[struct_name] = {m.name:m.type for m in node.decls} and get rid of about half of your visit_Struct code.

Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.
